# Does Ruby have containers like stacks, queues, linked-lists, maps, or sets?

Tags: ruby

I checked several Ruby tutorials online and they seemed to use array for everything. So how could I implement the following data structures in Ruby?

- Stacks
- Queues
- Linked lists
- Maps
- Sets

Comment: Well, an array can be a stack or queue by limiting yourself to stack or queue methods (push, pop, shift, unshift). Maps are hashes, and a Set class already exists (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html). You could implement a linked list using classes.

Comment: @James: I don't understand how stack and queue can use the same methods? Is one FIFO and the other is FILO?

Comment: Right, and using push / pop gives FILO behavior (stack), while using shift / pop gives FIFO behavior (queue).

Comment: By judicious usage of push, pop, shift, and unshift, you can mimic the behavior of queues and stacks. Ruby tends to not worry so much about interfaces.

Comment: @James - "shift / pop gives FIFO behavior" - should be "push / shift gives FIFO behavior"

Comment: I did a series of short blog post on this subject. In case you are still interested, you can read the first one here: https://medium.com/amiralles/mastering-data-structures-in-ruby-linked-lists-708347a30360

Answer (score 102, accepted):

(Moved from Comment)

Well, an array can be a stack or queue by limiting yourself to stack or queue methods (push, pop, shift, unshift).  Using push / pop gives LIFO(last in first out) behavior (stack), while using push / shift or unshift / pop gives FIFO behavior (queue).

Maps are  [hashes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html), and a [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html) class already exists.

You could implement a linked list using classes, but arrays will give linked-list like behavior using the standard array methods.

Comment: Yes, an array *can* be used this way, but isn't that rather slow when a linked list is called for?

Comment: The Array class stores an index to the first element being used in the array. Calling Array::Shift increments the index, so it runs in O(1) time (nothing is actually shifted). Array::Push runs in O(1), unless the array is full, in which case it needs to create a new array with more capacity and copy the original array. Source code: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c.

Comment: @James: I think you mean "unshift/pop" in your comment to your own answer.

Comment: @MichaelVenable your comment should be part of this answer; I knew about shift/unshift and push/pop but knowing about them in the context of wanting e.g. a deque is useless unless you also know that the implementation is efficient enough to be used in practice.

Comment: I don't understand why @MichaelVenable 's comment with false information got ~20 upvotes? Didn't anybody checkout the source code he kindly shared the link of? He seems to be talking about `unshift` but it's completely wrong to claim that it runs in O(1) and "nothing is shifted"?? See [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L1186) and [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L172)

Comment: @scaryguy: Looking over my previous comment, I think I was, in fact, talking about `Array::Shift`. In the case of using an array as a queue (the use case mentioned in the answer I responded to),  [shift](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/f6f388a5bdbd3d3a68bf18f3352ba2be12688639/array.c#L981) looks to me to run in O(1). I don't think `unshift` is relevant here, since it is not needed to implement a stack or queue, the two data structures referenced in the answer.

Comment: In case anyone still cares, I just wrote a post on how to implement linked lists in ruby (from scratch, not on top or arrays) https://medium.com/amiralles/mastering-data-structures-in-ruby-linked-lists-708347a30360

Answer (score 49):

I guess most of it is covered in above answers but just for summing it up for a better explanation:

Stack:

```
stack = []
stack << 2 # push 2 => stack = [2]
stack << 3 # push 3 => stack = [2, 3]
stack.pop  # pop => 3, stack = [2]
```

Queue:

```
# we have a Queue class
queue = Queue.new
queue << 2 # push 2 => queue = [2]
queue << 3 # push 3 => queue = [2, 3] (just a representation, it will be an object though)
queue.pop # pop 2
```

Linked List:

```
# A very simple representation
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node=nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end
end

class LinkedList

  def initialize(value)
    @head = Node.new(value)
  end

  def add(value)
    current = @head
    while !current.next_node.nil?
      current = current.next_node
    end
    current.next_node = Node.new(value)
  end
end

ll = LinkedList.new
ll.add(10)
ll.add(20)
```

Maps:

```
# Hash incase of ruby
a = {} (or a = Hash.new)
a['one'] = 1 # a = {"one"=>1}
a['two'] = 2 # a = {"one"=>1, "two"=>2}
```

Set:

```
# we have a Set class
require 'set'
s = Set.new         # <Set: {}>
s.add(1)            # <Set: {1}>
s.add(2)            # <Set: {1, 2}>
s.add(1)            # <Set: {1, 2}>
s.instance_of?(Set) # true
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this answer, the commands mentioned under the `Queue` section do not execute as expected in irb. I have `ruby 2.3.1` installed. It would be a good idea to include it in Documentation.

Comment: There's an slight issue in your LinkedList implementation, value of @next is not updated and is always `nil` @divyum

Comment: @Aashish thanks for pointing that out, just needed to change \@next to \@next_node.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, although not expressly in name. The `Array` class can be used as a stack, queue, or linked list. For example, `push` and `pop` make it behave like a stack. Ruby's `Map` is the `Hash` class. Ruby also has a `Set` class, although you have to import a module to use it (`require 'set'`).

Answer (score 10):

The Ruby language actually has a [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) class which can be used as .... wait for it... a Queue ;)

It is thread safe and easy to use.

The rest of @James answer is great and accurate.

Comment: Note that Queue class in Ruby -weirdly- doesn't have a `peek` implementation. Which means the only way to access to the front item is popping -so removing- it from the queue.

Comment: And even a `SizedQueue` by now.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't use arrays for queues or stacks unless you understand the overheads of using arrays for your problems and you're ok with those overheads.*

Arrays are intended to store a collection of items. They are not optimized for all stack and queue operations. Ruby just gives us the convenience of using arrays for queue- and stack-like operations. And this convenience comes with the price of a higher space or time complexity.

For example, shifting an array pointer instead of doing a proper `pop` increases the space complexity because it stores more data than actually required.

Or another example, rewriting your array instead of a proper `push` dramatically increases the time complexity because it requires moving each element of the array to another space on the disc.

Luckily, basic stacks are easily to implement. Here's an example:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :val, :prev
  def initialize(val:, prev:)
    @val = val
    @prev = prev
  end
end

class Stack
  attr_reader :length

  def initialize()
    @head = nil
    @length = 0
  end

  def push(val)
    node = Node.new(val: val, prev: @head)
    @head = node
    @length += 1
  end
  alias << :push

  def pop
    return nil unless @head
    pop_node = @head
    @head = pop_node.prev
    @length -= 1
    pop_node.val
  end
end
```

Usage example:

```
s = Stack.new
=> #<Stack:0x00007fd682045ed8 @head=nil, @length=0>
s.push 1
=> 1   # stack = [1]
s.push "2"
=> 2   # stack = [1, "2"]
s.push 3
=> 3   # stack = [1, "2", 3]
s.length
=> 3
s.pop
=> 3   # stack = [1, "2"]
s.pop
=> "2" # stack = [1]
s.pop
=> 1   # stack = []
s.length
=> 0
s.pop
=> nil
```

You can also add any other operation required by your use case like `peek` or `empty?` pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a great library [Algorithms by Kanwei](https://github.com/kanwei/algorithms) of data structures and algorithms with ~2.6K stars on Github.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'algorithms'

stack = Containers::Stack.new
max_heap = Containers::MaxHeap.new
```

Installation:

```
gem install kanwei-algorithms
```

Answer (score 0):

Heaps/ Priority Queue
A min heap/priority queue functionality can be achieved using sorted set.

Creation(Adding data to heap/PQ)

```
pq = SortedSet.new([3]) #=> #<SortedSet: {3}>
pq.add(1) #=> #<SortedSet: {1, 3}>
pq.add(6) #=> #<SortedSet: {1, 3, 6}>
```

Deletion(top priority element)

```
top = pq.first #1
pq.delete(top) #=> #<SortedSet: {3, 6}>, top is '1'
top = pq.first #3
pq.delete(top) #=> #<SortedSet: {6}>
```

Answer (score -2):

I would like to add Deque implementation (which is more generic in linear DS usage) in Ruby :

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :next, :prev
  def initialize(value, next_node, prev_node)
    @value = value
    @next = next_node
    @prev = prev_node
  end
end


class Deque
  attr_accessor :start, :end
  def initialize
    @start = @end = nil
  end

  def push_back(val)
    if @start.nil?
      @start = @end = Node.new(val, nil, nil)
    else
      @end.next = Node.new(val, nil, @end)
      @end.next.prev = @end
      @end = @end.next
    end
  end

  def pop_back
    if @start == @end #only one node
      @start = @end = nil
    else
      @end = @end.prev
      @end.next = nil
    end
  end

  def push_front(val)
    @start.prev = Node.new(val, @start, nil)
    @start = @start.prev
  end

  def pop_front
    if @start == @end #only one node
      @start = @end = nil
    else
      @start = @start.next
      @start.prev.next = nil
      @start.prev = nil
    end
  end

  def empty?
    @start.nil? && @end.nil?
  end

  def front
    @start.value unless self.empty?
  end

  def back
    @end.value unless self.empty?
  end

  def print(node)
    arr = []
    while node
      arr << node.value
      node = node.next
    end
    p arr
  end
end


q = Deque.new
q.push_back(1)
q.push_back(2)
q.push_back(3)
q.push_back(4)
q.print(q.start)
q.push_front(0)
q.push_front(-1)
q.print(q.start)
q.pop_back()
q.pop_back()
q.print(q.start)
q.pop_front()
q.pop_front()
q.print(q.start)
p q.front
p q.back
```

Output :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[-1, 0, 1, 2]
[1, 2]
1
2
```